# Ocaml list of ints to list of int lists (Opposite of flattening)

Tags: list, functional-programming, split, ocaml

With a list of integers such as:

```
[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]
```

How can I create a list of list of ints from the above, with all new lists the same specified length?

For example, I need to go from:

```
[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9] to [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]
```

with the number to split being 3?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is, please show some code you tried , and describe what went wrong when you tried it.

Comment: I have a way of getting a number of elements out, as seen below:
 `let rec iter listIn numAt col output =

    if (numAt mod (col+1)) = 0 then

      output

    else

      begin

 match listIn with

   [] -> []

 | x::xs -> (iter xs (numAt+1) col (output@[x]))

      end `


but am struggling in finding a way to combine the output of this into a list of lists.

Comment: The google search term is "sliding window" or moving window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you actually want is a function of type

```
val split : int list -> int -> int list list
```

that takes a list of integers and a sub-list-size. How about one that is even more general?

```
val split : 'a list -> int -> 'a list list
```

Here comes the implementation:

```
let split xs size =
  let (_, r, rs) =
    (* fold over the list, keeping track of how many elements are still
       missing in the current list (csize), the current list (ys) and
       the result list (zss) *) 
    List.fold_left (fun (csize, ys, zss) elt ->
      (* if target size is 0, add the current list to the target list and
         start a new empty current list of target-size size *)
      if csize = 0 then (size - 1, [elt], zss @ [ys])
      (* otherwise decrement the target size and append the current element
         elt to the current list ys *)
      else (csize - 1, ys @ [elt], zss))
      (* start the accumulator with target-size=size, an empty current list and
         an empty target-list *)
        (size, [], []) xs
  in
  (* add the "left-overs" to the back of the target-list *)
  rs @ [r]
```

Please let me know if you get extra points for this! ;)

Comment: I just ran into a bug: this code behaves incorrectly when called as `split [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9] 3`; it yields `[[1; 2; 3]; [4; 5; 6; 7]; [8; 9]]`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you give is a way to remove a given number of elements from the front of a list. One way to proceed might be to leave this function as it is (maybe clean it up a little) and use an outer function to process the whole list. For this to work easily, your function might also want to return the remainder of the list (so the outer function can easily tell what still needs to be segmented).

It seems, though, that you want to solve the problem with a single function. If so, the main thing I see that's missing is an accumulator for the pieces you've already snipped off. And you also can't quit when you reach your count, you have to remember the piece you just snipped off, and then process the rest of the list the same way.

If I were solving this myself, I'd try to generalize the problem so that the recursive call could help out in all cases. Something that might work is to allow the first piece to be shorter than the rest. That way you can write it as a single function, with no accumulators
(just recursive calls).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it this way:

```
    let split lst n =
      let rec parti n acc xs = 
        match xs with 
        | []              -> (List.rev acc, [])
        | _::_ when n = 0 -> (List.rev acc, xs)
        | x::xs -> parti (pred n) (x::acc) xs
      in let rec concat acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | xs -> let (part, rest) = parti n [] xs in concat (part::acc) rest
      in concat [] lst
```

Note that we are being lenient if `n` doesn't divide `List.length lst` evenly.
Example:
`split [1;2;3;4;5] 2` gives `[[1;2];[3;4];[5]]`

Final note: the code is very verbose because the OCaml standard lib is very bare bones :/ With a different lib I'm sure this could be made much more concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
let rec split n xs =
  let rec take k xs ys = match k, xs with
    | 0, _ -> List.rev ys :: split n xs
    | _, [] -> if ys = [] then [] else [ys]
    | _, x::xs' -> take (k - 1) xs' (x::ys)
  in take n xs []
```